# Can i say the browser or something is blocking thymeleaf nested loops?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have a project about spring boot and Thymeleaf. Inside the same project in different packages, i have two classes each having its own main method in its own package. These two classes are just some basic classes that handles user input on get method and add it as a list member. That's the brief explaination of the project base.

My actual question is that. If using nested loops in thymeleaf, is there something extra that should be added to maven pom file apart from the normal thymeleaf dependency? Because the reason is am getting different output for these identical codes. I tried digging the thymeleaf documentation but it would not help here. I have a code like this in index.html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<title>Note Book</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div > 
  <h1>Hello List!</h1>  
  <ol >
   <li th:each="items, iterStats : ${myList}" >
    <span th:text="${items}">hello! world</span>
   </li>
  </ol>
  <div>
   <h2>Add Content to list</h2>
   <form th:action="@{/}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="content" />
    <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
  </div> 
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

After running the controller and application file, i can see in the browser console that the oredered list's child contents are being rendered correctly.

But when i ran the other file i can see in the browser console that it looks like the browser or something is either blocking or harvesting the thymeleaf contents. Take note of the ordered list's child elements completely vanished. Really weird

this is the output from the console.

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <ol>
     
  </ol>
  <div>
   <form action="/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="content">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Could someone shed some light for here. This is really weird. I think i am the first one seeing something like this since i could not find anything about it online. Thank you in advance.

Comment: thymeleaf code is processed at the server-side and rendered into HTML. Client(browser) sees only the final HTML. There's something wrong with your server-side code - not populating `myList` perhaps.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But if I get the same result from two Windows 10 pcs?is it a Windows issue then? Or perhaps a network related? Is there any reason why my ISP or router should want to block this? Is there a work around to this?..May be someone else that has the same issue might learn from my experience.comes

Comment: No, nothing like that is possible.  It's more likely that the thymeleaf variable `${items}` is missing or empty in your 'other file'.

Comment: @Metroids. I have the variable present in the other file too as well. I just left it out in my question since its going to be a repetition. I can paste it here for you to see.  <body>
 <div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <ol>
   <li th:each="items : ${MyCollect}">
    <span th:text="${items}">Default</span>
   </li>  
  </ol>
  <div>
   <form th:action="@{/}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="content" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>  This is how it looks like. You can see for yourself. I have never seen this. before.

Comment: @Metroids. As you can see, the console output left out the child elements totally just bcos they have some server codes. Also the html documents thymeleaf declacration is completely omitted. Instead of  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">. The console is outputting only this : <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> and leaving out the thymeleaf part this one: xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">.  So this is really interesting for me right now. At the moment only one class can make interaction with the thymeleaf variables rendered properly.

Comment: I am using windows 10 and eclipse oxygen.3a and chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit).  At the moment i cant say what to conclude with. But i will dig down this hole. It may be a bug or something but i will have to find out the actual point before i can pin it somewhere.